# Bottom space in LaTeX template

Tags: spacing, header-footer, geometry, resume

I have been trying to remove space from bottom of the document in LaTeX.
I have used following command for the purpose. But It does not work.

```
\usepackage[top=0.2in, bottom=0.1mm, left=0.3in, right=0.5in, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
```

Below are some of other headers that I have used.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.2in, bottom=0.1mm, left=0.3in, right=0.5in, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}
\selectfont

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0.1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to remove following space from my document.
[image]

Comment: Please complete your example such that others can copy it as it and test it.

Comment: hi @daleif I added the complete example. Can you please check about my query. Thanks